# Dynamically generate JavaScript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I have this JavaScript code that is working well:

```
var lookup = {
            "dog-black":{url:'images/dog-black.jpg'},
            "dog-white":{url:'images/dog-white.jpg'},
            "cat-black":{url:'images/cat-black.jpg'},
            "cat-white":{url:'images/cat-white.jpg'}
        };
```

I'm tring to generate same code dynamically using PHP to have lines as much as there in the DB, like this:

```
var lookup = {            
            <?php                   
                    $sql = "SELECT name FROM swords ORDER BY animals, colors";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {                            
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo '"'.$row['name'].'":{url:images/'.$row['name'].'.jpg';                                   
                        }
                    } else {echo "No records";}                    
            ?>
        };
```

I tried to define the php code as string using quotes or heredoc and alert the string variable, but seems like the script is not excuted

note: i'm already connected to the DB before this part of code and pass data from/to it.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Where does your script fail? Does your PHP echo out something you can add here? Have you looked in the browsers console to see if javascript throws any errors?

Comment: Does your file extension .js or .php? it will not work if it is .js

Comment: Build an array in php, then json_encode it and echo it. DO NOT MANUALLY BUILD JSON! Your code as is will result in invalid json if no records are found, resulting in a js syntax error.

Comment: the java script code supposed to detect click inputs and use this array to get update the image url, the first code was working well, but with PHP it does nothing

Comment: the file extension is .php

Comment: Press F12, read the error. Go to the error in the src. You will see the invalid javascript object that php generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to echo this out manually.  What you can do is build the same structure in PHP, then use `json_encode`.

JSON is actually valid JavaScript code, so it will work.

Try it like this:

```
<?php
    $lookup = array();

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM swords ORDER BY animals, colors";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $lookup[$row['name']] = array('url' => 'images/'.$row['name'].'.jpg');                              
        }
    }
    else {
        //echo "No records";
    }                    
?>

var lookup = <?=json_encode($lookup); ?>;
```

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be a mistake in the `echo` in the while loop. You're not closing the string correctly, it is missing the closing part `},`. Which should look something like this:

```
echo '"'.$row['name'].'":{url:"images/'.$row['name'].'.jpg"},';
```